# ImportError: cannot import name <classname>

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

I have this:

```
import sys, struct, random, subprocess, math, os, time
from m_todo import ToDo

(rest)
```

Which results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "6.py", line 2, in <module>
from m_todo import ToDo
ImportError: cannot import name ToDo
```

My m_todo module:

```
import os

class ToDO:
    '''todo list manager'''

    def __init__(self):
            pass

    def process(self):
            '''get todo file ready for edition'''
            print(os.path.exists('w_todo.txt'),'\t\t\tEDIT THIS')
```

I read some similar questions, which suggested something about circular references, but it is not the case.

I also saw a suggestion about using relative imports, but trying that resulted in another error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "6.py", line 2, in <module>
from .m_todo import ToDo
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

This is like the third time I use Python, so it might be a silly mistake, but it's causing me some confusion since I'm importing other modules in the same way without any issues.

So... what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class is called `ToDO` (note the capitalisation), **not** `ToDo`.

Either fix your import:

```
from m_todo import ToDO
```

or the classname:

```
class ToDo:
```

Comment: Oh, my... I'm retarded. Thanks! (I'll accept your answer as soon as this allows me to)

Comment: It happens to all of us, don't worry.